# selecting from 2 tables. MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

How do i do select p.Quota without writing the long full name? right now i am doing

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.UserName, 
       p.Quota, 
       cs.StatusName 
  FROM CUSTOMERS AS c, 
       PRODUCTS AS p 
 LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERSTATUSTYPES as cs ON c.StatusId=cs.CustomerStatusId 
 LIMIT 1 ;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c.StatusId' in 'on clause'
```

However the column does exit and this code works:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.UserName, 
       cs.StatusName 
  FROM CUSTOMERS AS c
  JOIN CUSTOMERSTATUSTYPES as cs ON c.StatusId = cs.CustomerStatusId 
 LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: Why you don't use another JOIN for PRODUCTS table? Post schema of all tables and name of foreign key in table PRODUCTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing ANSI and non ANSI JOIN syntax with:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.UserName, 
       p.Quota, 
       cs.StatusName 
  FROM CUSTOMERS AS c, 
       PRODUCTS AS p 
  LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERSTATUSTYPES as cs ON c.StatusId=cs.CustomerStatusId 
  LIMIT 1 ;
```

Written using ANSI joins:

```
     SELECT c.id, 
            c.UserName, 
            p.Quota, 
            cs.StatusName 
       FROM CUSTOMERS AS c 
       JOIN PRODUCTS AS p ON --JOIN criteria goes here
  LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERSTATUSTYPES as cs ON c.StatusId = cs.CustomerStatusId 
      LIMIT 1;
```

...but I don't know what criteria you are using to join `PRODUCTS` to the `CUSTOMERS` table.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your implicit inner join followed by a left join. MySQL is trying to join PRODUCTS p on CUSTOMERSTATUSTYPES cs, without consideration for CUSTOMERS c.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 c.id, c.UserName, p.Quota, cs.StatusName 
FROM 
 CUSTOMERS AS c 
 INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS p 
 LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERSTATUSTYPES as cs ON c.StatusId=cs.CustomerStatusId 
LIMIT 1
```

Also, right now you have no clause relating records in CUSTOMERS to those in PRODUCTS... you're just doing a full join. Is this what you want to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.UserName, 
       p.Quota, 
       cs.StatusName 
FROM (CUSTOMERS AS c, PRODUCTS AS p) 
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERSTATUSTYPES as cs ON c.StatusId=cs.CustomerStatusId 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.